# grammar of "try as I might"

Tags: grammar, idioms, tenses, past-tense

I understand the phrase "try as I might..." to mean "I'm trying very hard and still..." and I'm comfortable using it in the present tense.

However, I don't understand the grammar of the phrase and therefore cannot really decide how to use it in the past tense.  Specifically, I am wondering how to say the equivalent of "I **was** trying very hard and still..."

Is it "try as I did" or does it just not change at all: "try as I might"?

Comment: It cannot be explained grammatically. It is an idiom. *Try as I might, I couldn't persuade him* = No matter how hard I tried, he couldn't be persuaded.

Comment: It should be noted that *try as I might* **is** in the past tense; *try as I may* is in the present.

Comment: Also, here are some other examples of the same construction: *Deny it who will* (even if anyone denies it, it's still true); *be that as it may* (even if that's true, so is the following). *Deny it who would* and *be that as it might* are the past-tense forms.

Comment: Today this is a frozen idiom. But was *might* originally in the subjunctive mood here?

Comment: @WS2 It can be explained grammatically. It is all subjunctive thing.

Comment: @Anonym I am not sure _deny it who will_ is idiomatic. It's not in Google search results or [Google books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22deny+it+who+will%22)

Comment: @L.Moneta I'm a bit confused, since it appears time and again in the link you've provided. If it seems unidiomatic to you, that's probably because the construction hasn't been productive for a very long time.

Comment: @Anonym Well, "deny it who will" doesn't seem to appear in any dictionaries. There are more false positives in the link above, such as "deny it! Who will attempt to refute it", and "as to deny it. Who will not be Blind to..." than hits where it is used as a phrase. That said, I guess you are right. Instances where it is used as a phrase all date back to the early 1800s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***[Try as someone might](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/try-as-someone-might)*** is a set phrase that is used in its 'fixed form' also in  the past tense:

> - used for saying that someone is making a very great effort but still cannot do something
>
>   - *Try as he might, he could not forget.*

(MacMillan Dict)

The expression exists also in the less common form of:

***[Try as  I may](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/try+as+I+may):***

> - Cliché a phrase that introduces an expression of regret or failure.
>
>   - *Bill: Try as I may, I cannot get this thing put together right. Andy: Did you read the instructions? Rachel: Wow! This place is a mess! Mother: Try as I might, I can't get Andrew to clean up after himself.*

(McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs)

***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=try%20as%20I%20might%2Ctry%20as%20he%20might%2Ctry%20as%20she%20might%2Ctry%20as%20they%20might&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctry%20as%20I%20might%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctry%20as%20he%20might%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctry%20as%20she%20might%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctry%20as%20they%20might%3B%2Cc0b)*** : *try as I/he/she/they might*